# Is there a way I can use minmax in css and space out columns without having whitespace?

Tags: html, css

I have some chunk of code that helps me lay out columns using HTML and CSS. The previous developer at my company used a function called minmax to render columns. I'm new to to the team and am trying to figure out how to go about fixing certain layout issues.
Every time I try to remove a column from my table using the checkbox functionality that's already implemented OR expand my window on a super-wide monitor, I see a lot of spacing between columns that I don't understand the origin of. I want to space it out evenly across the page.

I've tried changing the line of code that implements the rendering of the table but it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

The HTML code that lays out the columns is :

```
<div class="HistoricFinancialsContainer">
    <!-- Start TitleRegion PAgeRegion column-->
    <div class="TitleRegion PageRegion">
        <div class="CenterVertically Green tophead">
            <div>Titles</div>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let title of Titles">
            <div *ngIf="title.Children.length === 0" class="CenterVertically toggleTitle"
                [ngClass]="title.CssClasses.ComputeStyles()">
                <div class="titleVC" [innerHTML]="title.Text" title={{title.Tooltip}}></div>
            </div>
            <ng-container *ngIf="title.Children.length > 0">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let children of title.Children">
                    <div class="CenterVertically toggleTitleContent contentAlign"
                        [ngClass]="children.CssClasses.ComputeStyles()">
                        <div [innerHTML]="children.Text" title={{children.Tooltip}}></div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
                <div class="CenterVertically Collapsible toggleTitle" [ngClass]="title.CssClasses.ComputeStyles()">
                    <div (click)="CollapseChildren(title)">
                        <i>
                            <i class='fa'
                                [ngClass]="{'fa-arrow-circle-down': title.CssClasses.Contains('IsCollapsed') !== false, 'fa-arrow-circle-up': title.CssClasses.Contains('IsCollapsed') === false}"></i>
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="titleVC" [innerHTML]="title.Text" title={{title.Tooltip}}></div>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <!-- End HistoricFinancials Title Region column-->

    <!-- Start HistoricRegion PageRegion Column when 1yr only is displayed -->
    <div class="HistoricRegion"
        *ngIf="HistoricFinancialsObj.SelectedEndYear - HistoricFinancialsObj.SelectedStartYear === 0">
        <div class="PageRegion history1yr">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let year of Years">
                <div class="CenterVertically Green Year tophead yrHead"
                    [ngStyle]="{'grid-column': GetYearColumnComputation(year), 'grid-row': 1 }">
                    <div (click)="NavigateToHistoricalDetailFinancials(year)">
                        <div>
                            {{year}}<div class="fa fa-pencil-square-o">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let title of Titles">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of GetVisibleHistoricalColumns(year)">
                        <ng-container *ngIf="column.ShortName !== 'Lock'">
                            <div *ngIf="title.Children.length === 0 && title.Columns === undefined"
                                class="CenterVertically  titleRow"
                                [ngStyle]="{'grid-column': GetBlankTitleComputation(year, column), 'grid-row': GetParentRow(title)}">
                                <div class="CenterVertically contentAlign">
                                    {{ GetDataPoint(year, title, column, false) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="title.Children.length > 0">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let children of title.Children">
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of GetVisibleHistoricalColumns(year)">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="column.ShortName !== 'Lock'">
                                    <div class="CenterVertically tophead contentAlign"
                                        [ngStyle]="{'grid-column': GetBlankTitleComputation(year, column), 'grid-row': GetChildRow(title, children)}"
                                        [ngClass]="children.CssClasses.ComputeStyles()">
                                        <div class="CenterVertically contentAlign">
                                            {{ GetDataPoint(year, children, column, false) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of GetVisibleHistoricalColumns(year)">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="column.ShortName !== 'Lock'">
                                <div class=" CenterVertically titleRow contentAlign"
                                    [ngStyle]="{'grid-column': GetBlankTitleComputation(year, column), 'grid-row': GetParentRow(title)}">
                                    <div class="CenterVertically contentAlign">
                                        {{ GetDataPoint(year, title, column, false) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let column of GetVisibleHistoricalColumns(year)">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="column.ShortName !== 'Lock'">
                        <div class="CenterVertically LtGrey"
                            [ngStyle]="{'grid-column': GetBlankTitleComputation(year, column), 'grid-row': GetBlankSpaceIndex() + 1}">
                            <div>{{column.ShortName}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.HistoricFinancialsContainer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 50%) 1fr auto auto;
        border: 2px solid $cbre-green;

        .fa {
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            padding: .25rem 0 .5rem .35rem;

            .fa-angle-down {
                color: black;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }

            .fa-lock {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }

            .fa-arrow-circle-up {
                padding: .5rem .5rem 0 .25rem;
            }
        }

        checkbox {
            justify-content: center;

            input[type='checkbox'] {
                box-shadow: none;
                width: 1rem;
                margin-top: -.25em;
            }
        }

        .PageRegion {
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-rows: 2.25rem;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            justify-content: left;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-transition: height 2s;
            transition: height 2s;

            .Collapsed {
                display: none;
            }

            >div {
                border-right: .1px solid #ced4da;
                padding: 0 .5rem;

                &.Green {
                    background-color: $cbre-green;
                }

                &.LtGrey {
                    background-color: rgb(233, 231, 231);
                    font-size: .6rem;
                    font-weight: 600;
                    color: $cbre-green;
                    height: 2rem;
                    border-bottom: 2px solid $cbre-green;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

            .contentAlign {
                justify-content: right;
            }

            .yrHead {
                color: white;
                justify-content: center;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-family: $fontFamily;
                font-size: 1rem;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
                grid-area: 1 / 1 / auto / span 5;

                &:hover {
                    color: rgb(255, 255, 152);
                }

                .fa.fa-pencil-square-o {
                    font-size: 1rem;

                    &:hover {
                        color: rgb(255, 255, 152);
                    }
                }
            }

            .yrHeadCurrent {
                color: white;
                justify-content: center;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-family: $fontFamily;
                font-size: 1rem;
            }

            .titleRow {
                justify-content: right;
                color: $cbre-green;
                font-weight: 700;
                border-top: .5px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.25);
            }
        }

        //title column styles
        .TitleRegion {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 2fr;
            justify-content: left;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 0 3px -2px rgb(202, 201, 201);
            box-shadow: 3px 0 3px -2px rgb(202, 201, 201);

            >div {
                color: $cbre-green;
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            .tophead {
                color: white;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-family: $fontFamily;
                font-size: 1rem;
                padding-left: 1rem;
            }

            .toggleTitle {
                color: $cbre-green;
                font-weight: 400;
                border-bottom: 2px solid $cbre-green;
                line-height: 1.5rem;
                justify-content: left;
            }

            .toggleTitleContent {
                color: black;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 1rem;
                margin-left: 2rem;
                border-left: none;
                justify-content: left;
            }

            .subheadTitle {
                color: $cbre-black;
                opacity: .8;
                font-weight: 800;
                font-size: 1rem;
                margin-left: .5rem
            }

            .titleVC {
                font-size: 1rem;
                font-weight: 800;
                padding: .35rem 0 0 .5rem;
            }
        }

        // Current Year styles
        .YearZeroRegion {


            .PageRegion {
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
                border-right: 2px solid $cbre-green;

            }
        }

        //end of YearRegion
    }
```

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jylkg.png)

I've tried to change the 25% to 75% but that essentially just expands the first column of the table to be wide instead of auto-fitting the entire table across the screen.

Comment: Hi, Sarthak. Not sure, if the issue is in minmax function.
Can you add some of your HTML and CSS for this table, so we can reproduce it more precisely?

Comment: Hi @Serhiy, I can add my HTML and CSS but there's a lot of code there and I'm not sure if I should be adding hundreds of lines of code here. Would adding a little bit more of a snippet help?

Comment: Sure. Snippet would be perfect.

Comment: @Serhiy Just added more!

Comment: @SarthakSachdeva saw it. It seems over tangled to solve it just by looking at it)
Not sure if it's style issue at all.
 
It would be really helpful to have the possibility to take a look at the compiled code on the website or Codepen(https://codepen.io/danielkocsan/pen/ejGGYy)

Provide that, please, if you have such a possibility. If not, provide an example of data, that being rendered by this code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without other code, but you should try to add one more **auto** to the *grid-template-columns* property to define the width of the 4th column.

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 25%) 1fr auto auto;
```

Take a look at it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns